# VS2012 IntelliSense Suggestion Mode permanent setting?

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Is there a way to make VS2012 IntelliSense Suggestion Mode permanent, by maybe setting it somewhere in TOOLS -> Options? Or maybe by setting it somewhere in the registry?

I really like the concept, and it makes TDD a lot easier if you know IntelliSense won't auto-complete your new class names. However, VS2012 doesn't always remember this setting on new solutions/projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change between the Completion Mode and Suggestion Mode in Visual Studio 2012 by pressing `Strg + Alt + Space`. This toggles between those two modes.

Or you can change it using `Edit -> IntelliSense -> Toggle Completion Mode`.

Currently there is no way to make the `Suggestion Mode` as default for all projects.

Comment: I guess I'll have to wait for a service pack or something similar. +1 for bothering to try and answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN lists the [Devenv Command Line Switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) of which **/Command** switch can be used to solve this problem.
Append `/Command "Edit.ToggleCompletionMode"` to the shortcut's Target property.

Or launch Visual Studio from the command line with: `devenv /Command "Edit.ToggleCompletionMode"`